# Как разрезать строку в массив по 2 символа?

Tags: javascript

Например строка: `FFFFFF`
Как её разрезать по 2 символа, что бы получился массив: `["FF","FF","FF"]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так:

```js
function split(text) {
    return text.match(/.{1,2}/g);
}

console.log(split("one two three"));
```

Comment: Только с пустой строкой null получается...

Comment: А какой результат по вашему должен быть?

Comment: Либо пустой массив, либо массив с пустой строкой - на усмотрение автора. По мне - просто пустой массив.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function f(text) {
    return text.match(/..?/g) || [];
}

console.log(f(""));
console.log(f("a"));
console.log(f("ab"));
console.log(f("abc"));
console.log(f("123456789"));
console.log(f("1234567890"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```